# Logging across multiple app domains

Tags: c#, logging, service, .net-remoting

I need to do some logging in my application and my Visual Studio Solution contains several dll's (and thus multiple app domains).  I thought just creating a static class for my logging would work, but I found out that static classes aren't so static across app domains.  From what I read, there are ways around this that require remoting/services/etc.  I've also noticed free solutions such as NLog, etc.  Do any of the freeware logging applications support cross domain logging easily?  What would be the easiest way to implement this functionality (freeware solution, service, other..)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Contains several dll's (and thus
>   multiple app domains).

um no several Dll's means several assemblies. Try inspecting the results of [GetAssemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx) on AppDomain.CurrentDomain to see what I mean.

This means you should be able to use NLog, Log4Net, or Enterprise Library with a single Configuration with no problems.

Comment: The author is asking about logging frameworks which will capture log events from multiple app domains, whether you believe its possible or not.

Comment: @gap. Perhaps you have found a different meaning to the OP's first sentence and the supposed constraint it put on the Application's logging requirements than I did. Perhaps you should ask the OP to clarify rather than just telling me I'm wrong about what they were thinking. You're also free to provide your own answer

Comment: Just because it uses several dlls doesn't mean he's not loading them into seperate app domains. I have a solution with "several" dlls and I'm purposly using app domains to load them so why not answer the question instead of assuming hes not using app domains like he said he was

Comment: @JacquelineLoriault I refer you to gap's comment and my response above. If you feel the OP meant something different than what I thought, comment on the question or make your assumptions and provide your own answer. You can also put a bounty on the question or ask a question if you really need and answer for logging for multiple app domains.